# a: hover, color is not changing

Tags: html, css

A: HOVER doesn't apply the color change, only the background, even if I put there the !important .

## css

menu

```
.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(images/menu_resize_bg.png) top no-repeat;
  height: 90px;
  width: 962px;
}

.menu ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 600px;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 0;
  height: 45px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000000;
  font: normal 17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu ul li a span {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px 7px 20px;
  background: none;
}

.menu ul li a small {
  display: block;
  font: normal 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /*color:#eea83b;*/
  color: #fefefe;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #fefefe **!important**;
  background: url(images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right;
}

.menu ul li a:hover span {
  color: #fefefe **!important**;
  background: url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left;
}

.menu ul li a.active {
  background: url(images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right;
}

.menu ul li a.active span {
  background: url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and paste the html, too.

Comment: <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact<small>Write a message</small></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clr"></div>

Comment: Your code looks correct. See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/88k5cy9j/5/)

Comment: @herhh: in your link it works, at my page it doesn't work.                                                             http://tantrissimo.sk/index.html

Comment: then the error must be elsewhere in your html/css. I think you should debug it by commenting out some sections, step by step.

Comment: @herhh: many thanks for your help!

Comment: my pleasure! It would be great, if you accept the answer below, so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some wrong css comments in this part:

```
.menu ul li a small {
    display: block;
    font: normal 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /color: #eea83b;
    / color: #fefefe;
    text-transform: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

`/color` needs to look like: `/*color: ... */`.

Comment: There are no single line comments in CSS. You need to open and close them `/* color: #000; */`. The browser will probably be ignoring them anyway as it's an invalid selector. And changing this block definitely won't help the OP as his issue is with hover effects

Comment: thanks, lets close the comments topic. a: hover is able to change the background but not the color, where can be the issue?

Comment: @tomas, I made a working fiddle with your css code... you can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/88k5cy9j/3/)